# Wait for user input after automatically entering initial input in bash

Tags: bash, shell, alias, vpn

I have an alias to connect to my vpn, which is
`alias vpnc="printf 'username\npassword\n' | /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect vpnhost.com"`
This works fine when there is only username and password to be piped. I have another situation where I have to enter a token from my yubikey after the password is typed. That is the username and password will be typed automatically and the bash command should wait for the token input. How can we do this?

Comment: I suggest to use a function. See with `bash`: `help function`

Comment: I'm not an expert on bash, but wouldn't `alias vpnc="read && printf 'username\npassword\n$REPLY' |..."` work?

Comment: you are looking for [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)

Comment: @Cyrus Function works really fine
@crizzis that works too, except it should be `read token` and `${token}`
Thanks for the help. Why did I not think about this earlier?!

Comment: expect works too I guess but not necessary here.

Comment: Is it possible to simply close the question? I have got what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the full solution how you managed the script to wait for the token.

Here is how I solved it, we get an sms passcode (Answer) after successful sign in with username and password.

First step is to select group (0 in this case), then sign in with username and password, then wait for the passcode to arrive as an sms. Then enter it and press enter.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Extract password from keychain
pw=$(security find-generic-password -a myusername -s profilename -w)

/usr/bin/expect -c '
set timeout 20

spawn "/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn"

expect "VPN>" { send "connect vpn.contoso.com\n" }
expect "*roup*" { send "0\r" }
expect "*sername*" { send "myusername\r" }
expect "*assword*" { send "'${pw}'\r" }
expect "*nswer*" { interact -o "\r" exp_continue }
expect "state: Connected" { send "exit\r" }
interact
'
```

Comment: This is not a real answer to the original question, even though the original poster got everything he needed from the comment section.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez
I didn't have enough reputation to comment.
expect was suggested in the comments. So I showed a way to solve it since no one else provided a full answer.
The initial question was in regards to wait for token input.